# An error with Magento 2 Admin panel page/Unable to access the admin page - Rest of the site is still fine

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento2.4

When logging into my admin panel it's throwing the error below, causing me to be unable to access the admin panel.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Item with identifier Magefan_Community::elements does not exist

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Item with identifier Magefan_Community::elements does not exist
<pre>#1 Magefan\Community\Plugin\Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\BuilderPlugin->afterGetResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:146]
#2 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#3 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Menu/Builder/Interceptor.php:23]
#4 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->getResult() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php:153]
#5 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->_initMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php:116]
#6 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->getMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php:365]
#7 Magento\Backend\Model\Url->_getMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php:325]
#8 Magento\Backend\Model\Url->getStartupPageUrl() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:187]
#9 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->_processUrlKeys() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Request/BackendValidator.php:175]
#10 Magento\Backend\App\Request\BackendValidator->validate() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/CompositeValidator.php:40]
#11 Magento\Framework\App\Request\CompositeValidator->validate() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:192]
#12 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:147]
#13 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:29]
</pre>
```

I haven't changed anything, but other accounts user access, and it began throwing this error. Any assistance would be much appreciated.